# add element to the DOM after load()

Tags: jquery

I cannot add element `<p>TEST</p>` before `<h1>` tags in my page

Here is my code (simplified) :

index.html

```
<div class="container" id="page_body"> BLABLA </div>
```

properties.html

```
<h1>Properties Management</h1>
```

menu.html

```
<li><a href="#" id="link_properties">Properties Repository</a></li>
```

JS

```
$("#page_menu").on('click', '#link_properties', function(e) {
    $("#page_body").load("properties.html"); // Properties
    $('h1').before('<p>TEST</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `callback` method. Assuming you want to insert `<p>` before `<h1>Properties Management</h1>` in  *properties.html*

```
$("#page_menu").on('click', '#link_properties', function(e) {
    $("#page_body").load("properties.html", function(){
        $('h1').before('<p>TEST</p>');
    }); 
});
```